# New item field on top of DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, datagridview, bindinglist

`DataGridView` in .Net has built-in support for adding new items at the bottom. Last row is treated in a special way. The `IBindingSource` interface supports this through AddNew/EndNew/CancelNew methods. Is it possible to change this to allow adding items in the **top row** of the grid instead?

I know I can do `sourceList.Insert(0, item)` programmatically for a start, but devil is in the details and I wonder if there is already a way to do this.

The data is coming from a bound `IBindingList` (not a database).

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a insert DateTime column and sort the grid to this column ? (one solution)
If you really really need this feature, consider using a 3rd party grid like JANUS or DevExpress and check if they support it.

also check out:

[SO Old Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263913/how-to-set-the-insert-new-row-as-first-row-in-datagridview)

Comment: IIRC, even with a sorted `DataView` it appends to the bottom and only re-sorts when you commit the row. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: (I mention `DataView` because it is one of the few types that supports the gamut of interfaces consumed by `DataGridView` in this scenario)