# How do I move newly added row to the topof the DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

`datagridview1.Add()` will add a new row to the `datagridview` but it will be placed at the bottom of all rows. But how do I move this newly added row to the top of all the rows in it?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263913/how-to-set-the-insert-new-row-as-first-row-in-datagridview

Answer (score 1):

Try adding new items by inserting them:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, item)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't directly manipulate gridview's data source.

instead you could utilize IList collection and use Insert Method such as

```
IList<Product> source = new List<Product>();
/// populate source with products
/// 
source.Insert(0, new Product("Table"));
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
```